An error occured after adding the initial Migration while accessing the Microsoft.extension.hosting services
Once I have added my first Migration Add-Migration InitialMigration, it display this error below,
An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Failed to load configuration from file 'C:\Users\Ammad\source\repos\EmployeesProject\EmployeesProject\appsettings.json'.
Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. The exception 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[EmployeesProject.Context.ApplicationDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'EmployeesProject.Context.ApplicationDbContext'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
Please let me know the solution as I need to add the first migration. thanks
Please find my code below for just one simple class created Employee.cs
namespace EmployeesProject.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
}

My application db context class code is mentioned below
using EmployeesProject.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace EmployeesProject.Context
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>contextOptions): base(contextOptions)
        {

        }

        // Code First Approach
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
}

The appsetting.json code is below
{

     "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "Server": "DESKTOP-DFBVCE0;Database:Employees; User Id={username};Password:{password}; TrueServerCertificate:True"
      },
    
      "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Information",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
        }
      },
      "AllowedHosts": "*"
    }

Please find Program.cs below,
namespace Employeeproject
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}

The updated appsetting.json code is below now
{


  {
    "ConnectionStrings": { "DefaultConnection": "Server={User};Database={Employees};User Id={Ammadlogin};Password={ammadpass1};MultipleActiveResultSets=true" }

  },

  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}


Please share the Program.cs where you register dbcontext.

Please find the program.cs code as well. I have added in the textbox. @sa-es-ir

Just make sure the appsettings.json is copy to output always.

what is your data base ? is it sql Server ?   i think your ConnectionStrings isn't correct and also you need to passe  it to DbContext

My connection string looks fine now without error but the db name is Employees as created on SQL Server and Server name is showing only "User" as I go to the properties in SQL Management studio.

First i would like to suggest you to use the correct connection string as the one you are using is not in right format:
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source={Sql server name];Database={Databse};Trust Server Certificate=True;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

Program.cs:
namespace Employeeproject
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.
            var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}

Make sure you have installed below packages:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

Run below commands:
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
dotnet ef database update

OR:
Add-Migration InitialMigration
Update-Database

Dbcontext code:
using EmployeesProject.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace EmployeesProject.Context
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
}


I have this warning on the Logging part down below the connection string code , "Only one top level document is allowed in JSOn format.

@AmmadHassan could you share your updated appsettings.json file

it's shared. Right now there is no error but if you could correct my dbcontext code updated. thanks

@AmmadHassan i have shared the updated dbcontext code you could try

could you please confirm where you have written the updated DbContext code. The yesterday one has errors on appconfig. Please confirm. thanks

@AmmadHassan you can see in my post

your ConnectionStrings should be something like :
 "ConnectionStrings":  {"DefaultConnection": "Server=DESKTOP-DFBVCE0;Database=Employees;User Id={user};Password={Pass};MultipleActiveResultSets=true"},

and your ApplicationDbContext should be something like :
    namespace EmployeesProject.Context
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        IConfiguration appConfig;
        public ApplicationDbContext(IConfiguration config, DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> contextOptions) : base(contextOptions)
        {
            appConfig = config;
        }


        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {
            if (!options.IsConfigured)
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(appConfig.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

            }

        }
        // Code First Approach
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
}

   

but what is necessary is to Find your Program.cs or startup where your WebApplication.CreateBuilder exists and change it like blow :
       var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    ConfigurationManager configuration = builder.Configuration;
    var ConnectionS =
  configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    builder.Services
        .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
            b => b.UseSqlServer(ConnectionS)
              .UseLazyLoadingProxies());

it is better to reviewed:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/

What should be the name of my GetConnectionString("NameOFYourCNStringInAppsettings")); ?   You can see my connection string code above mentioned in appsetting.json

in this scenario it is "DefaultConnection" which you can change it

public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(IConfiguration config, DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        appConfig = config;
    }
    public DbSet<Employee> Mytest { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        if (!options.IsConfigured)
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(appConfig.GetConnectionString("NameOFYourCNStringInAppsettings"));

        }

    }

}

}

Please find my ApplicationDbContext.cs file. The appConfig doest not exist in the current context. Please let me know how to fix the error for appConfig in this case.

@AmmadHassan I changed my answer and  it  is much more suitable for your scenario now , and what is really important is to find your  Program.cs or startup where your Application Configuration exists and change it like that

If you get any new error just share it with me
